# Create CloudFrontWebDistribution with viewerCertificate, how to configure

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am deploying my single page app to an S3 bucket via the AWS-CDK.

Current stack code is:

```js
this.distribution = new CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, `${this.props.applicationName}Distribution`, {
      originConfigs: [
        {
          s3OriginSource: {
            s3BucketSource: this.dashboardBucket,
            originAccessIdentity: dashboardIdentity
          },
          behaviors: [{
            isDefaultBehavior: true
          }],
        },
      ],
      aliasConfiguration: {
        acmCertRef: awsConfig.acm_arn,
        names: [url]
      },
      errorConfigurations: [
        {
          errorCode: 403,
          responseCode: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/'
        },
        {
          errorCode: 404,
          responseCode: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/index.html'
        }
      ]
    });
```

However, in AWS-CDK 1.133 I got the message that `aliasConfiguration` is deprecated. So I am looking at `viewerCertificate: ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate()` but I am not sure how to use it.

Before I could refer to the ARN of the Certificate that I already created in the Certificate Manager.
Can I use the `Certificate` class to get a reference of the existing ACM resource and use that with the ViewerCertificate?

AWS's docs are not super clear in examples, just all references.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you. I didn't have time yet to try it out since we are in the middle of a release.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @gshpychka how do I add the Alternate domain name ? It used to be part of the AliasConfiguration but I find it very unclear where to configure that atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Certificate` construct to get a reference to an existing certificate. Use [`Certificate.fromCertificateArn()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-certificatemanager.Certificate.html#static-fromwbrcertificatewbrarnscope-id-certificatearn)

```js
viewerCertificate: ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate(
    Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, "my_cert", awsConfig.acm_arn)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution proposed didn't allow me to add my custom cname.
Luckily I found another solution which does:

```
viewerCertificate: {
  aliases: [url],
  props: {
    acmCertificateArn: awsConfig.acm_arn,
    sslSupportMethod: 'sni-only',
    minimumProtocolVersion: 'TLSv1.1_2016',
  }
},
```

which was mentioned here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1802